# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error while drawing a polygon

Tags: java, swing, polygon, java-2d

hi there i'm having a trouble while i'm trying to draw a polygon. first of all, when i try to draw a polygon with using `addPoint(int x, int y)` method and giving coordinates one by one there is no problem, polygon could be drawed perfectly. however, if i give the coordinates as an array (an integer array for x coordinates and y coordinates) compiler gives error. this is the working code as you can see,

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Polygon poly = new Polygon();

    poly.addPoint(150, 150);
    poly.addPoint(250, 100);
    poly.addPoint(325, 125);
    poly.addPoint(375, 225);
    poly.addPoint(450, 250);
    poly.addPoint(275, 375);
    poly.addPoint(100, 300);

    g2.drawPolygon(poly);

}
```

but if i use the `xpoints` and `ypoints` array (which are defined in Graphics class for polygon) it doesnt work properly.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Polygon poly = new Polygon();

    poly.xpoints[0]=150;
    poly.xpoints[1]=250;
    poly.xpoints[2]=325;
    poly.xpoints[3]=375;
    poly.xpoints[4]=450;
    poly.xpoints[5]=275;
    poly.xpoints[6]=100;      

    poly.ypoints[0]=150;
    poly.ypoints[1]=100;
    poly.ypoints[2]=125;
    poly.ypoints[3]=225;
    poly.ypoints[4]=250;
    poly.ypoints[5]=375;
    poly.ypoints[6]=300;

    g2.drawPolygon(poly.xpoints, poly.ypoints, 7);

}
```

i will appreciate if you can help and thanks anyway.

Comment: what is the array size of xpoints and ypoints ??

Comment: i thought that it should be 7 cause there are 7 integer elements for each array ?

Comment: try `poly.xpoints = new int[7]; poly.ypoints = new int[7];`

Comment: @gefei Make that an answer...

Comment: Why are you overriding the paint(...) method??? Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method.

Comment: i read from some tutorials and examples etc. ? does it matter a lot ?

Comment: @quartaela, get rid of those tutorials and examples. Read the Sun tutorials. Overriding paint() is done in AWT. When using Swing you override paintComponent(). You should also be invoking super.paintComponent(...) at the start of your method. Yes, there is a difference. I wouldn't have taken the time to make my suggestion if there wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> i thought that it should be 7 cause there are 7 integer elements for
>   each array ?

You have to first `initialize your array` and then `populate the array with elements`.

```
    poly.xpoints = new int[7]; // initializing the array
    poly.xpoints[0]=150;       //populating the array with elements.
    poly.xpoints[1]=250;
    poly.xpoints[2]=325;
    poly.xpoints[3]=375;
    poly.xpoints[4]=450;
    poly.xpoints[5]=275;
    poly.xpoints[6]=100;
```

Same applies to YPoints as well.

If you looking for a Dynamic Array use one of the [**List**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementing class's from Java collection Framework like ArrayList.

```
List<Integer> xPoints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
xPoints.add(150);
xPoints.add(250);
...
```

Comment: i thought that array was defined dynamically cause it didnt work even when i use `poly.xpoint.lenght`. but yes your solution is working thanks for it.

Comment: @quartaela Array is not dynamic. ArrayList is.

Comment: @PremGenError `npoints` will not be initialized in your case. You cannot just set the array. Look at the `Polygon ` source.

Comment: @PremGenError yeah i got it that's perfect !

Answer (score 2):

Try and initialize the Polygon using the arrays prebuilt.  You can create the arrays before hand and pass them into the constructor for the Polygon.

```
public Polygon(int[] xpoints, int[] ypoints, int npoints)
```

Comment: well i can use this method it will be more readable :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the size of the array is? Is it even initialised?

Quick Google found this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#xpoints
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/GraphicsdrawPolygonintxPointsintyPointsintnPoints.htm