# about drawing a Polygon in java

Tags: java, swing, polygon, java-2d, paintcomponent

hi there i'm trying to improve myself about java2D and first of all i'm dealing with drawing polygons. However, i can not see the polygon on frame. I read some tutorials and examples but as i said i face with problems. here is the sample code of drawing a polygon;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class jRisk extends JFrame {


    private JFrame mainMap;
    private Polygon poly;

    public jRisk(){

        initComponents();

    }

    private void initComponents(){

        mainMap = new JFrame();
        mainMap.setSize(800, 600);
        mainMap.setResizable(false);

        mainMap.setVisible(true);
        mainMap.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        int xPoly[] = {150,250,325,375,450,275,100};
        int yPoly[] = {150,100,125,225,250,375,300};

        poly = new Polygon(xPoly, yPoly, xPoly.length);

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponents(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawPolygon(poly);

    }   

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new jRisk();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`JFrame` does not have a [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method. Add the [`@Override` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) and you will get a compile time error.

1) Use `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` (you would than add `JPanel` to the `JFrame` viad `JFrame#add(..)`)

2) Override `getPreferredSize()` to return correct `Dimension`s which fit your drawing on Graphics object or else they wont be seen as `JPanel` size without components is 0,0

3) dont call `setSize` on `JFrame`... rather use a correct `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPrefferedSize()` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` after adding all components but before setting it visible

4) Have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) specifically about [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

5) watch class naming scheme should begin with a capital letter and every first letter of a new word thereafter should be capitalized

6) Also you `extend JFrame` and have a variable `JFrame`? Take away the `extend JFrame` and keep the `JFrame` variable as we dont want 2 `JFrame`s and its not good practice to extend `JFrame` unless adding functionality

Here is your code with above fixes (excuse picture quality but had to resize or it was going to 800x600):

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JRisk {

    private JFrame mainMap;
    private Polygon poly;

    public JRisk() {

        initComponents();

    }

    private void initComponents() {

        mainMap = new JFrame();
        mainMap.setResizable(false);

        mainMap.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        int xPoly[] = {150, 250, 325, 375, 450, 275, 100};
        int yPoly[] = {150, 100, 125, 225, 250, 375, 300};

        poly = new Polygon(xPoly, yPoly, xPoly.length);
        JPanel p = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawPolygon(poly);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 600);
            }
        };
        mainMap.add(p);
        mainMap.pack();
        mainMap.setVisible(true);

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JRisk();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As per your comment:

> i am preparing a map which includes lots of polygons and yesterday i
>   used a JPanel over a JFrame and i tried to check if mouse was inside
>   of the polygon with MouseListener. later i saw that mouseListener gave
>   false responds (like mouse is not inside of the polygon but it acts
>   like it was inside the polygon). so i deleted the JPanel and then it
>   worked

Here is updated code with `MouseAdapter` and overridden `mouseClicked` to check if click was within polygon.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JRisk {

    private JFrame mainMap;
    private Polygon poly;

    public JRisk() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        mainMap = new JFrame();
        mainMap.setResizable(false);

        mainMap.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        int xPoly[] = {150, 250, 325, 375, 450, 275, 100};
        int yPoly[] = {150, 100, 125, 225, 250, 375, 300};

        poly = new Polygon(xPoly, yPoly, xPoly.length);

        JPanel p = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawPolygon(poly);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 600);
            }
        };

        MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);

                if (poly.contains(me.getPoint())) {
                    System.out.println("Clicked polygon");
                }

            }
        };
        p.addMouseListener(ma);//add listener to panel
        mainMap.add(p);

        mainMap.pack();
        mainMap.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JRisk();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: well actually i am preparing a map which includes lots of polygons and yesterday i used a JPanel over a JFrame and i tried to check if mouse was inside of the polygon with MouseListener. later i saw that mouseListener gave false responds (like mouse is not inside of the polygon but it acts like it was inside the polygon). so i deleted the JPanel and then it worked.

Comment: @quartaela The problem was not the JPanel IMO it was else where

Comment: well you are perfect !. thanks a lot. and could i ask one more question ?. what is the difference between calling `new JRisk()` and calling it inside the `run()` method. does it differ so much. i guess it is relevant with concurrency ?

Comment: Glad to help... Yes It has do do with concurrency. All Swing components should be created and manipulated on Event Dispatch Thread. The `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` blocks do that for us :)

Answer (score 3):

`JFrame` does not extend `JComponent` so does not override `paintComponent`. You can check this by adding the `@Override` annotation.

To get this functionality extract `paintComponent` to a new class which extends `JComponent`. Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)` rather than `super.paintComponents(g)`.

Comment: ok but in here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167342/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-error-while-drawing-a-polygon` @camickr says that i should use paintComponent() if i going to use swing ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponents(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawPolygon(poly);

}
```

With

```
protected void paint(Graphics g){

    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawPolygon(poly);

}
```

Comment: well i was using paint() method however, someone told that if i going to use swing rather than awt than i should override `paintComponent()`

Comment: ok now it says i override the paint method however it doesnt show the polygon