# Did the user click the right shape?

Tags: java, shapes, mouselistener

I am trying to make an education game were children will be ask what location a province is, just like the link below. I have hit a problem, I do not know how to tell the program whether or not he had hit the right shape.
If you guys could give me some suggestions on how to tackle the problem it will be a greatly appreciated.

http://online.seterra.net/en/vgp/3006

This is what I have so far:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class CPTprograss2 extends JPanel
{
       static Polygon[] polygons;
       Polygon selected;
       static String province = "";

public CPTprograss2 ()
{
    polygons = new Polygon [13];

    int[] bcx = {95, 78, 108, 26, 11, 16, 41};
    int[] bcy = {267, 204, 141, 87, 161, 208, 241};
    polygons [0] = new Polygon (bcx, bcy, 7);
    int[] abx = {96, 124, 157, 110, 81};
    int[] aby = {258, 277, 160, 142, 196};
    polygons [1] = new Polygon (abx, aby, 5);
    int[] skx = {126, 185, 201, 160};
    int[] sky = {277, 290, 174, 160};
    polygons [2] = new Polygon (skx, sky, 4);
    int[] mnx = {187, 232, 232, 275, 253, 243, 206};
    int[] mny = {291, 294, 258, 215, 195, 180, 175};
    polygons [3] = new Polygon (mnx, mny, 7);
    int[] onx = {233, 265, 287, 310, 343, 337, 329, 355, 391, 363, 348, 341, 321, 299, 280, 235};
    int[] ony = {295, 309, 301, 327, 333, 344, 373, 359, 328, 324, 316, 274, 256, 231, 215, 259};
    polygons [4] = new Polygon (onx, ony, 16);
    int[] qbx = {349, 374, 412, 425, 431, 445, 470, 488, 432, 422, 413, 433, 409, 396, 382, 380, 357, 334, 343, 340, 361, 341, 346, 344, 347};
    int[] qby = {319, 329, 323, 295, 285, 279, 259, 219, 240, 236, 210, 201, 161, 174, 167, 155, 145, 148, 174, 187, 214, 234, 266, 274, 313};
    polygons [5] = new Polygon (qbx, qby, 25);
    int[] nflx = {414, 420, 437, 490, 492, 538, 492, 445};
    int[] nfly = {213, 232, 238, 217, 266, 251, 201, 186};
    polygons [6] = new Polygon (nflx, nfly, 8);
    int[] peix = {461, 474, 475, 464};
    int[] peiy = {290, 287, 292, 293};
    polygons [7] = new Polygon (peix, peiy, 4);
    int[] nox = {424, 432, 454, 457, 464, 459, 445, 436, 436, 428};
    int[] noy = {299, 285, 285, 291, 298, 307, 316, 303, 298, 298};
    polygons [8] = new Polygon (nox, noy, 10);
    int[] nbx = {455, 462, 472, 488, 493, 488, 486, 481, 468, 469, 463, 457};
    int[] nby = {325, 328, 312, 297, 287, 282, 290, 296, 300, 308, 312, 320};
    polygons [9] = new Polygon (nbx, nby, 12);
    int[] ykx = {18, 39, 72, 89, 94, 84, 82, 89, 86, 92, 95, 90, 101, 88, 19};
    int[] yky = {73, 97, 119, 129, 121, 113, 90, 73, 61, 51, 40, 34, 19, 8, 71};
    polygons [10] = new Polygon (ykx, yky, 15);
    int[] nwtx = {90, 112, 163, 205, 214, 172, 146, 151, 176, 208, 221, 219, 195, 184, 177, 153, 146, 140, 119, 104, 92, 96, 94, 89, 90, 86, 85, 87, 95, 93};
    int[] nwty = {129, 146, 161, 172, 122, 102, 58, 50, 52, 60, 37, 26, 18, 20, 36, 42, 38, 28, 22, 20, 35, 45, 53, 58, 75, 85, 103, 114, 120, 126};
    polygons [11] = new Polygon (nwtx, nwty, 30);
    int[] nnx = {205, 244, 255, 265, 259, 290, 301, 305, 314, 316, 331, 346, 361, 389, 395, 393, 372, 392, 392, 384, 375, 361, 350, 338, 317, 299, 287, 259, 242, 220, 208, 155, 147, 172, 216, 207};
    int[] nny = {173, 178, 154, 143, 134, 139, 142, 151, 148, 135, 124, 119, 131, 137, 126, 114, 97, 98, 89, 81, 75, 63, 52, 46, 37, 28, 28, 24, 27, 39, 60, 50, 56, 100, 121, 171};
    polygons [12] = new Polygon (nnx, nny, 36);
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int max = 13;
    int drawNum[] = new int [max];

    drawNum [0] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;

    while (drawNum [1] == drawNum [0])
    {
        drawNum [1] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [2] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [2] == drawNum [1]))
    {
        drawNum [2] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [3] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [3] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [3] == drawNum [2]))
    {
        drawNum [3] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [4] == drawNum [0]) ||
            (drawNum [4] == drawNum [1]) ||
            (drawNum [4] == drawNum [2]) ||
            (drawNum [4] == drawNum [3]))
    {
        drawNum [4] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [5] == drawNum [0]) ||
            (drawNum [5] == drawNum [1]) ||
            (drawNum [5] == drawNum [2]) ||
            (drawNum [5] == drawNum [3]) ||
            (drawNum [5] == drawNum [4]))
    {
        drawNum [5] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [6] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [6] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [6] == drawNum [2]) || (drawNum [6] == drawNum [3]) ||
            drawNum [6] == drawNum [4] || drawNum [6] == drawNum [5])
    {
        drawNum [6] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [7] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [7] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [7] == drawNum [2]) || (drawNum [7] == drawNum [3]) ||
            drawNum [7] == drawNum [4] || drawNum [7] == drawNum [5] || drawNum [7] == drawNum [6])
    {
        drawNum [7] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [8] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [8] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [8] == drawNum [2]) || (drawNum [8] == drawNum [3]) ||
            drawNum [8] == drawNum [4] || drawNum [8] == drawNum [5] || drawNum [8] == drawNum [6] || drawNum [8] == drawNum [7])
    {
        drawNum [8] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [9] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [9] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [9] == drawNum [2]) || (drawNum [9] == drawNum [3]) || drawNum [9] == drawNum [4] ||
            drawNum [9] == drawNum [5] || drawNum [9] == drawNum [6] || drawNum [9] == drawNum [7] || drawNum [9] == drawNum [10])
    {
        drawNum [9] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [10] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [10] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [10] == drawNum [2]) || (drawNum [10] == drawNum [3]) || drawNum [10] == drawNum [4] ||
            drawNum [10] == drawNum [5] || drawNum [10] == drawNum [6] || drawNum [10] == drawNum [7] || drawNum [10] == drawNum [8] || drawNum [10] == drawNum [9])
    {
        drawNum [10] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [11] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [11] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [11] == drawNum [2]) || (drawNum [11] == drawNum [3]) || drawNum [11] == drawNum [4] ||
            drawNum [11] == drawNum [5] || drawNum [11] == drawNum [6] || drawNum [11] == drawNum [7] || drawNum [11] == drawNum [8] || drawNum [11] == drawNum [9] || drawNum [11] == drawNum [10])
    {
        drawNum [11] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    while ((drawNum [12] == drawNum [0]) || (drawNum [12] == drawNum [1]) || (drawNum [12] == drawNum [2]) || (drawNum [12] == drawNum [3]) || drawNum [12] == drawNum [4] ||
            drawNum [12] == drawNum [5] || drawNum [12] == drawNum [6] || drawNum [12] == drawNum [7] || drawNum [12] == drawNum [8] || drawNum [12] == drawNum [9] || drawNum [12] == drawNum [11] || drawNum [12] == drawNum [11])
    {
        drawNum [12] = (int) (Math.random () * max) + 0;
    }

    String state[] = new String [13];
    state [0] = "British Columbia";
    state [1] = "Alberta";
    state [2] = "Saskatchewan";
    state [3] = "Manitoba";
    state [4] = "Ontario";
    state [5] = "Quebec";
    state [6] = "Newfoundland and Labrador";
    state [7] = "Prince Edward Island";
    state [8] = "New Brunswick";
    state [9] = "Nova Scotia";
    state [10] = "Yukon";
    state [11] = "Northwest Territories";
    state [12] = "Nunavut";


    Selecting coordinates = new Selecting ();
    Selector selector = new Selector (coordinates);
    coordinates.addMouseListener (selector);

    JFrame f = new JFrame ("Name the Province");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    for (int v = 0 ; v < 13 ; v++)
    {
        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea (15, 20);
        txt.setText ("Where is " + state [drawNum [v]] + "?");
        //System.out.println(state[drawNum[v]]);
        txt.setEditable (false);

        //txt.setLineWrap (true);
        txt.setBounds (30, 400, 300, 60);
        f.getContentPane ().add (txt);

        if (state [drawNum [v]].equals (state[drawNum[v]]))
        {
            System.out.println ("correct");
        }


    }





    f.getContentPane ().add (coordinates);
    f.setSize (560, 600);
    f.setLocation (100, 100);
    f.setVisible (true);






}


protected void draw (Graphics g)
{
    //super.paintComponent (g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint (RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for (int j = 0 ; j < polygons.length ; j++)
    {
        Color color = Color.blue;
        if (polygons [j] == selected)
            color = Color.red;
        g2.setPaint (color);
        g2.draw (polygons [j]);
    }
}


Selecting selecting;


public void Selector (Selecting s)
{
    selecting = s;
}


public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
{
    Point p = e.getPoint ();
    Polygon[] polygons = selecting.polygons;

    for (int j = 0 ; j < polygons.length ; j++)
    {
        if (polygons [0].contains (p))
        {
            //selecting.setSelection (polygons [0]);
            //System.out.println ("British Columbia");
            province = "British Columbia";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [1].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Alberta");
            province = "Alberta";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [2].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Saskatchewan");
            province = "Saskatchewan";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [3].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Manitoba");
            province = "Manitoba";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [4].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Ontario");
            province = "Ontario";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [5].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Quebec");
            province = "Quebec";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [6].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Newfoundland and Labrador");
            province = "Newfoundland and Labrador";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [7].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Prince Edward Island");
            province = "Prince Edward Island";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [8].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("New Brunswick");
            province = "New Brunswick";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [9].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Nova Scotia");
            province = "Nova Scotia";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [10].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Yukon");
            province = "Yukon";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [11].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Northwest Territories");
            province = "Northwest Territories";
            break;
        }
        else if (polygons [12].contains (p))
        {
            //System.out.println ("Nunavut");
            province = "Nunavut";
            break;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}


public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
{

}
```

}

Comment: The Selecting class is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link has your answer, with minor modifications: [about drawing a Polygon in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188238/about-drawing-a-polygon-in-java)

In the paintComponent method (probably in your Selecting class), use a loop to draw all the polygons.

```
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            for(Polygon poly : polygons) {
                g.drawPolygon(poly);
            }
        }
```

In the mouseClicked handler (probably in your Selector), use a loop:

```
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            super.mouseClicked(me);

            for (int i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
                if (polygons[i].contains(me.getPoint())) {
                    System.out.println("Clicked polygon " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```